# Unknown directive " " in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com + HttpUploadProgressModule

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to understand why almost same nginx/HttpUploadProgressModule config works under my local Ubuntu and does not on Linode server.

Long story short: nginx was configured from sources in order to include HttpUploadProgressModule module support ( (http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadProgressModule#Installation , https://github.com/masterzen/nginx-upload-progress-module )

Same 1.2.4 nginx was used, same virtual hosts configuration both locally and on server. Now I got an error reloading nginx on server:

```
Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "  " in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com:12
location ~ (?<upload_form_uri>.*)/x-progress-id:(?<upload_id>\d*) {
#Line 12 below #
rewrite ^ $upload_form_uri?X-Progress-ID=$upload_id; 
# Line 12 above #
}
```

but it works just fine locally. Below are nginx-V and `ldd /usr/sbin/nginx` comparison, which led me nowhere so far neither did Google search:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tough... did you try to use unnamed backreferences?

Comment: @Michel FeldheimExcuse me, what do you mean? I'm not server administrator, so "unnamed backreferences" in current context sounds scary for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something apparently causes the nginx config parser to fail working properly.

The regular expressions with named backreferences drew my attention.
Nginx is using the PCRE library to parse regular expressions, so this should be valid syntax

See this to understand capturing groups and named/unnamed backreferences 
http://regular-expressions.mobi/named.html

Try this

```
location ~ (.*)/x-progress-id:([0-9]+) {
    set $upload_form_uri $1;
    set $progress_id $2;
    rewrite .* $upload_form_uri?X-Progress-ID=$progress_id;
}
```

Same meaning but a bit more basic syntax.
If this does not help, more investigation will be required.

Comment: Using `set` directive in such cases is a bad practice. You should use named captures as much as possible. Please, report the bug if something is not working properly.

Comment: Without `set` i can use the backreference from the rewrite source only. I prefer `set` over evaluating a regexp twice, your thoughts?